# ngx datatable not rendering at all

Tags: angular

I get a blank square that's shown in the browser when I run this. 
Below are the files :

template.html:

```
<div>
<ngx-datatable class="material"
[rows]="rows"
[columnMode]="'force'"
[columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

Inside a component's constructor after subscribing to a service:

```
this.columns = data.columns;
this.rows = data.rows;
```

I also tried `this.columns.push` but no change.
I have imported the 3 css files in  inside `style.scss.` Then I tried putting these in component's `scss` file.

Comment: can you add component code here

Comment: better grammar and more coding